# Udacity OnTheMap: Unable to parse data into JSON using JSONSerialization

Tags: json, swift3

I am working on the Udacity OnTheMap project and for some reason am unable to successfully convert data in JSON. I attempted to post on Udacity's forum but am not getting prompt response, and hence the post here. The function for authenticating to udacity is as such:

```
func authenticateToUdacity(_ email: String, _ password: String, completionHandlerForAuth: @escaping (_ session: AnyObject?, _ error: NSError?) -> Void) {
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.udacity.com/api/session")!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpBody = "{\"udacity\": {\"username\": \"\(email)\", \"password\": \"\(password)\"}}".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data, response, error in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
            completionHandlerForAuth(nil, NSError(domain: "authenticateToUdacity", code: 1, userInfo: nil))
            return
        }
        let range = Range(uncheckedBounds: (5, data!.count - 5))
        let newData = data?.subdata(in: range) /* subset response data! */
        print(NSString(data: newData!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
        print(NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)


        let parsedResult: [String: AnyObject]!
        do {
            parsedResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: newData!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: AnyObject]
            print(parsedResult)                
        } catch {
            print("Error parsing result as JSON")
            completionHandlerForAuth("" as AnyObject?, nil)               
            return
        }

        completionHandlerForAuth("" as AnyObject?, nil)

    }
    task.resume()        
}
```

Note that the reason for subdata is because the first 5 characters are used for security purposes and we are required to truncate the first 5 characters.

Here, the I am always getting the "Error parsing result as JSON" and I am suspecting that the data and newData are of the wrong format. My suspicion came when I print both newData(truncated) and data(not truncated) as above, and the results are as such respectively:

> {"account": {"registered": true, "key": "xxxxxxxxxx"}, "session": {"id": "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy", "expiration": "2017-02-24T13:29:05.59684
>   )]}'
>
> {"account": {"registered": true, "key": "xxxxxxxxxx"}, "session": {"id": "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy", "expiration": "2017-02-24T13:29:05.596840Z"}}

In any case, I tried serialising both, but both doesn't seem to parse successfully. Anybody any help pls?

Answer (score 0):

You need to drop the first 5 characters before parsing

something like this

```
guard let data = data.dropFirst(5) else {
        return
        }
```

your code will become

```
func authenticateToUdacity(_ email: String, _ password: String, completionHandlerForAuth: @escaping (_ session: AnyObject?, _ error: NSError?) -> Void) {
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.udacity.com/api/session")!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpBody = "{\"udacity\": {\"username\": \"\(email)\", \"password\": \"\(password)\"}}".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data.dropFirst(5) else {
        return
        }
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
            completionHandlerForAuth(nil, NSError(domain: "authenticateToUdacity", code: 1, userInfo: nil))
            return
        }
        let range = Range(uncheckedBounds: (5, data!.count - 5))
        let newData = data?.subdata(in: range) /* subset response data! */
        print(NSString(data: newData!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
        print(NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)


        let parsedResult: [String: AnyObject]!
        do {
            parsedResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: newData!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: AnyObject]
            print(parsedResult)                
        } catch {
            print("Error parsing result as JSON")
            completionHandlerForAuth("" as AnyObject?, nil)               
            return
        }

        completionHandlerForAuth("" as AnyObject?, nil)

    }
    task.resume()        
}
```